# Devise edit password page - access user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need to customise the Devise edit password page to include a few details that are included in the User model.

I had a quick look online but couldn't find any documentation mentioning the views having access to the user model.

Is there a way to access it?

**Edit:** I've got the views et al, it's specifically about accessing the user model in the edit password page. I need to personalise it.

Answer (score 1):

```
= render :template => 'devise/passwords/edit', :locals => {:resource => current_user,:resource_name => User }
```

Try this in view
For devise_errors include `devise_helper.rb` or write your own error handler

Answer (score 0):

Check out the devise Wiki on github ( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki ), furthermore what you prolly want to do is run the following command in your app home.
`rails g devise:views` or for a specific model `rails g devise:views modelName`

that will create the tree of views under app/views/devise.

In the views, refer to the object as `resource`

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
...
```

You can safely delete the views that you don't need to over ride, if you want to use haml or slim for views, that is fine too, see this wiki page => https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i've already got my templates, question was how to access the user model (as in the modal instance) in the Edit Password (app/views/devise/password/edit.html.haml) file.

Comment: the user model should be pulled in as `resource`

Comment: Cheers. The model is certainly there as `resource`, but, I can't seem to access the models properties. Not even it's ID. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: Can you post the code you have for the view and your user model?

Comment: Uploaded here: https://gist.github.com/992255
The resource output works, dumping the object hash, but the second line (where I output the users email) shows up as nothing, same with all the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Run this and it will copy your views to a folder called 'shared' for R<3 and 'devise' for R3.

```
rails g devise:views
```

You can then customize the views. You should be able to understand everything in those volders it's just Rails MVC stuff.

If you have a specific devise model you should specific the model by name:

```
rails g devise:views users
```

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate devise:views users`

This will generate the views for the user model. You can then manually edit the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing.  I temporarily put `resource.inspect` into the view, and saw that it was a User instance with all attributes `nil` except for `reset_password_token`.  Given that, I accessed the corresponding User record using brute force:

```
User.find_by_reset_password_token(resource.reset_password_token)
```

Or to be more generic:

```
resource.class.find_by_reset_password_token(resource.reset_password_token)
```

You can use that directly in view, or assign it to an instance variable in the controller if you're overriding the Devise controller.  Be aware that it will return nil if the token is invalid.  (It seems Devise doesn't check the validity of the token until after the user submits the form, so you can get to this view with an invalid token.)

*Update 03/2014*

As of devise 3.1, you need to digest the token before lookup:

```
resource.class.find_by_reset_password_token(Devise.token_generator.digest(resource.class, :reset_password_token, resource.reset_password_token))
```